# Possible race condition in OpenMP parallel for loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, shared-memory, race-condition

I'm using [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) to parallelize a for loop. This program uses the [Gurobi C API](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/c_api_details.html).

```
GRBupdatemodel(model);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int batch = 0; batch < n_batch; ++batch)
{

    int cind[1 + n_max];
    for (int j = 0; j < n_max; ++j)
    {
        cind[1 + j] = n_sum + j;
    }

    double cval[1 + n_max];
    cval[0] = 1;

    GRBmodel* model_copy = GRBcopymodel(model);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_sum; ++i)
    {
        cind[0] = i;
        for (int k = 0; k < n_min; ++k)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n_max; ++j) 
            {
                cval[1 + j] = -*((double*) PyArray_GetPtr(array, (long []) {batch, i, j, k}));
            }
            GRBaddconstr(model_copy, 1 + n_max, cind, cval, GRB_LESS_EQUAL, 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    GRBoptimize(model_copy);
    GRBgetdblattrarray(model_copy, GRB_DBL_ATTR_X, 0, n_sum, values[batch]);
    GRBgetdblattrarray(model_copy, GRB_DBL_ATTR_X, n_sum, n_max, max_strategy[batch]);
    GRBgetdblattrarray(model_copy, GRB_DBL_ATTR_PI, 1, n_sum * n_min, (double *) min_strategies[batch]);
    GRBfreemodel(model_copy);
}
```

Each iteration of this loop writes to a different section of the arrays `values`, `max_strategy`, and `min_strategies`.

Removing `#pragma omp parallel for` yields correct results. Adding it yields incorrect results, including nan values. Thus I suspect there is a race condition in my loop, but I haven't been able to find it. Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I only see two types of writes in my loop body:

- To `cind`, `cval`, and `model_copy` (by [GRBgetdblattrarray](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/c_getdblattrarray.html)), which are local variables declared inside the loop body and therefore private to each thread.
- To non-overlapping sections of `values`, `max_strategy`, and `min_strategies`.

Comment: It could be an issue with the library. I recommend you contact support, as we cannot examine the source (afaik) to verify a race condition or not

Comment: What happens if you pre allocate all your temporary copies of the model?  It’s hard to say what the library functions do but the copy method always acts on the same object from all threads. I know a copy should be Thread safe in the ideal case. I wouldn’t bet on it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_env2.html

According to the docs the models in each loop iteration are not independent copies. They share the same environment variable. This means they potentially read/write from the same memory. If you ensure each copy has its own environment it might succeed.

I see you are calling this code from python. If you only use C is to use multithreaded computation I would recommend using pure python code with joblib or dask to have the same result. The race condition would also be apparent in python as the different models cannot be serialized. See this [support question](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360047219672-Using-Gurobi-with-joblib-in-Python)

Comment: I ended up creating a separate model from scratch with `GRBnewmodel` inside the loop body instead of copying from a template model with `GRBcopymodel`. It seems to work properly and is faster than the non-parallel solution.